# Symfony2 installing vendors in Windows

Tags: php, symfony

I'm new in symfony2, I have an instance when I'm trying to installing vendors in windows using the below command.

```
php app/console bin/vendors install
```

after this command I got the below errors [image: See the below image]

In mac and linux this command works but in windows it is not working properly. In windows  After this command it deletes some of the folder in vendor .

Does anybody knows about this why it happens in windows?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I helped a poor (actually he uses windows seven like you, so he must be kind of rich) friend of mine the other day with the very same issue. Just install git-bash and you'll be fine. Plus, git-bash will provide you with a waaaaaaay better cli than what you have for the moment.
You can install it [from here](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/). Make sure you check the git-bash option.

Comment: and as a bonus, you get linux commands and coloration inside git-bash's shell... enjoy!