# Updating Symfony 2.0.9 the right way

Tags: symfony, xampp

I'm developing a Tool using Symfony 2. Since my Version of Symfony is a bit old, I would like to update. My current installation is the one "with vandors" and I'm using it under Win7 with XAMPP.
I feel somehow stupid, but even after searching the internet for over an hour, I didn't figure out how to update correctly to Version .15

You would be a great help, if you could give me some dumb-secure instructions on this, because all I've done so far to install or patch software was running an exe-file.

Hopefully my english was good enough to point out what my problem is, but nethertheless I excuse myself for all mistakes.

Greetings GrimReaper1908

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The update steps are always given in the release announcement (see [Symfony 2.0.15 released](http://symfony.com/blog/symfony-2-0-15-released)):

> If you already have a project based on the Symfony Standard Edition
>   2.0.x, you can easily upgrade to 2.0.15 by getting the new [deps](https://raw.github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/v2.0.15/deps) and [deps.lock](https://raw.github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/v2.0.15/deps.lock) files. Then, run the vendors script (it also clears your cache):

```
./bin/vendors install
```

If you modified deps file to include additional vendors you'll have to manually merge it with the latest Symfony one.

Vendors script requires git client to work. You'll have to install it.

Since you're on windows: [Symfony2 installing vendors in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8165577/symfony2-installing-vendors-in-windows)

Comment: Thank you!!
Installing the git-bash was the missing information I was looking for. Now everything works fine ;)